# Hot to reduce itemsep globally into choice environment?

Tags: exam

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question This is a question
        \begin{choices}
            \choice one
            \choice two
            \choice two
        \end{choices} 
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I want to reduce the itemsep value inside the choices environment so that it affects all the choices enviroment that I have into the document, so I don't want to manually specify `\itemsep5pt` for each environment. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\choiceshook`:

```
\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}
```

Change `0pt` as you wish.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question This is a question
        \begin{choices}
            \choice one
            \choice two
            \choice two
        \end{choices}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]